# How to navigate from a page to another page in Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm developing a mobile application based on the Onsen UI (and PhoneGap + AngularJS).
I want to navigate from the Settings.html template/page to the StartPage.html template/page. But when both of them have the `</ons-navigator>` tag, it doesn’t work. Can someone help me.
Thanks

**App.js (AngularJS)**

```
//Start page
app.controller('StartPage', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.menu.setSwipeable(false);         
         $scope.LogInPage = function () {          
        $scope.myNav.pushPage('LogIn.html', { animation: 'slide' })
    };
    $scope.SignUpPage = function () {
        $scope.myNav.pushPage('SignUp.html', { animation: 'slide' })
    };
}]);
    //Settings
app.controller('Settings', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.LogOut = function () {
        $scope.navSettings.resetToPage('StartPage.html', { animation: 'slide' });
    };
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!--StartPage.html-->
 <ons-template id="StartPage.html">
    <ons-navigator var="myNav">
        <ons-page ng-controller="StartPage" style="background-color:#4383cd">

            <img src="images/Logo.png" height="150px" style=" display: block; margin-top:40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

            <button class="button button--outline" style="width:95%; display:block; margin-top:60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color:white; color:white" ng-click="LogInPage()">LOG IN</button>
            <button class="button button--outline" style="width:95%; display:block; margin-top:10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color:white; color:white" ng-click="SignUpPage()">SIGN UP</button>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>

  <!--Settings.html-->
 <ons-template id="Settings.html">
    <ons-navigator var="navSettings">
    <ons-page ng-controller="Settings">
        <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Settings</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <button ng-click="LogOut()" class="button button--large">Log out</button>
    </ons-page>
     </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to check the docs if you didn't do it yet: 
http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html
http://onsen.io/reference/javascript.html

You don't need a navigator per page, just one:

```
<ons-navigator var="myNav" page="StartPage.html">
</ons-navigator>

<!--StartPage.html-->
 <ons-template id="StartPage.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="StartPage" style="background-color:#4383cd">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" height="150px" style=" display: block; margin-top:40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

        <button class="button button--outline" style="width:95%; display:block; margin-top:60%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color:white; color:white" ng-click="LogInPage()">LOG IN</button>
        <button class="button button--outline" style="width:95%; display:block; margin-top:10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-color:white; color:white" ng-click="SignUpPage()">SIGN UP</button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

  <!--Settings.html-->
 <ons-template id="Settings.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="Settings">
        <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
                    <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
                </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">Settings</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <button ng-click="LogOut()" class="button button--large">Log out</button>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Check that your JS and Controllers are OK with these changes. Hope it helps!

#### UPDATE

with OnsenUI v2 release, the attribute `startPage` has changed to `page`. you could check this out on [OnsenUI v2 Navigator](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular1/ons-navigator.html#attributes)

Comment: I have already try this but it doesn't work. My mobile application is with a slide-menu with navigator. This is a similar example of mobile application. (http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/qEyvxB). And I want to make that you can log out of my application and then comes on the "StartPage.html". This page have no sliding menu. I hope you can help me

Comment: If the sliding menu is the parent component of your app, then just use `myMenu.setMainPage('StartPage'); myMenu.setSwipeable(false);'` to log out. Make it swipeable again if you log in.